# how to ensure unique names within an arm template?

Tags: c#, .net, azure-devops, azure-logic-apps, azure-rm-template

**How do we ensure that connection resources have unique names?**

We have approximately 100 logic apps that have connections to things like sftp and blob storage. An example would be:

```
"azureblob_1_Connection_Name": {
  "value": "azureblob-1"
},
"azureblob_1_Connection_DisplayName": {
  "value": "my-blob-con"
},
"azureblob_1_accountName": {
  "value": "blobdocumentstor"
}
```

Because of lack of automation, another logic app might be using the same connection name: `azureblob-1`, yet it may have different properties like the `accountName` might be different:

```
"azureblob_1_accountName": {
  "value": "differentdocstor"
}
```

When deploying a logic app with the same connection name, it will replace the existing connection!

**How do we ensure that connections are not overwritten?**

**Is it possible to enforce within an arm template that a certain value will be unique ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use some prefix with your resource name and the `uniqueString` function withtin the arm template to generate a unique name.

Example:

```
"functionApp_appServicePlanName": {
  "defaultValue": "[concat('assamplefnappsvc',uniqueString(resourceGroup().id))]",
  "metadata": {
    "description": "Name of the app service plan to host function app."
  },
  "type": "string"
}
```

The above default value for the resource will be automatically generated . You can also write custom logic to generate unique string and pass it from PowerShell / .NET wherever you are deploying your template.

Answer (score 2):

you can use something like time arm template deployment started and pass that in the template and generate unique name based on that. all the arm template functions are deterministic so you always get the same output if you pass the same input. Date\time function is not yet implemented (afaik). Before that happens you need to rely on external source to generate names\prefixes\something for the arm template to generate unique names.

But this leads to a problem where you can not update existing stuff, unless you know the "seed" you supplied the first time it ran.

another way of enforcing that - use separate resource group for each deployment, I know its not exactly optimal, but that would work (not sure about logic app connections tbh, are they globally unique? if they are then this doesnt work).

you could probably create a template that does filtering (kinda) on existing resources, but its not going to be straight forward (its going to be really hacky, easier to implement this logic elsewhere).

Comment: There's a `uniqueString` function available . It can be relied upon

Comment: no, its deterministic, meaning you always get the same output if you pass in the same input.

Comment: and there's no non-deterministic input that I can find to provide to it.